# How to use Scrapy FormRequest in a loop

Tags: python, parsing, scrapy, web-crawler, reactor

I'm trying to create a spider that would put the words from a list into a cite's search input one by one and then parse text from the resulting pages.

It works fine for one word, but I can't make it work for the entire list. Guess I should (somehow) put the loop inside the spider?

My code is below. It was produced as a compilation of several other Stack Overflow advices. The problem is that the crawler gets updated to the last word in `words` and ignores the rest of the list. And I can't put the `crawler.start()` inside the loop due to the 'ReactorNotRestartable' error.

```
class FirstSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ruscorpora'

    def start_requests(self):
            yield scrapy.Request('https://ruscorpora.ru/new/search-main.html', callback=self.form_input)
    
    def form_input(self, response):
            return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={'req': the_word}, callback=self.parse_freq)
    
    def parse_freq(self, response):
        xpath = "/html/body/div[4]/p[3]/span[3]/text()"
        message = response.xpath(xpath).extract_first()
        
        if message is None:            #in case there isn't a word like that
            result.append(0)
        else:
            result.append(message)

words = ['parrot','patriot','partjbndonfc']
result = []

for the_word in words:
    crawler = CrawlerProcess()
    crawler.crawl(FirstSpider, the_word)

crawler.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could something like this

```
class FirstSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ruscorpora'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request('https://ruscorpora.ru/new/search-main.html', callback=self.form_input)
    
    def form_input(self, response):
    
        words = ['parrot','patriot','partjbndonfc']
        for word in 
            yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={'req': word}, callback=self.parse_freq)
    
    def parse_freq(self, response):
        xpath = "/html/body/div[4]/p[3]/span[3]/text()"
        message = response.xpath(xpath).extract_first()
        
        if message is None:            #in case there isn't a word like that
            result.append(0)
        else:
            result.append(message)

result = []

crawler = CrawlerProcess()
crawler.crawl(FirstSpider)

crawler.start()
```